# powershell script to set dnsserverforwarder

Tags: powershell

I have quite a number of Servers where I need to set DNSServerForwarders with certain IP address

**Example**:

```
server1 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (stand for ip address)

server2 - aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (stand for ip address)

server3 - yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa (stand for ip address)
```

Is there way I can do it with powershell script? I can do manually 1 by 1 but as I need to ensure that the correct DNSServerForwarders IP address is correctly for all the servers weekly.

Is there way I can do it with powershell script? I can do manually 1 by 1 but as I need to ensure that the correct DNSServerForwarders IP address is correctly for all the servers weekly.

Comment: What did you try from your side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Set-DnsServerForwarder` cmdlet to reset the forwarders to specific settings, eg :

```
Set-DnsServerForwarder -IPAddress "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"
```

which will then reset them to those three IP addresses. Alternatively you can use `Add-DnsServerForwarder` to simply add an entry to an existing list of forwarders, though from your description I suspect the former is what you're after. `Get-DnsServerForwarder` can be used to see what is currently configured.

Since you also mention needing to do this on multiple servers, if this is within a single network enviroment (eg you can connect from the current server to the other servers needing updating) you can add the `-ComputerName` parameter to specify the server you want to update, and then update each of them from a single server, rather than need to run it individually on each server.

```
Set-DnsServerForwarder -IPAddress "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3" -ComputerName Dnsserver1
```

Comment: i try using "Set-DnsServerForwarder -IPAddress "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3" -ComputerName Dnsserver1" and it is working. but I get a bit messy when running multiple update for 20+ servers. can i export the result out to csv file by using "append"

Comment: What do you mean by it gets messy?

Comment: For taking inputs for multiple servers/IP addresses you can save the input values in a CSV file and import the same using `Import-Csv '.\filepath\input.csv'` anf then put it to the command suggested by Keith: `Import-Csv '.\filepath\input.csv' | %{ Set-DnsServerForwarder -IPAddress $_.ColumnName1FromCSV -ComputerName $_.ColumnName2FromCSV}`